# can't resolve drawable resource put into drawable-xhdpi

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-background

Ok this is very stupid but i can't find a way out.
As a brief test I put bg.png into drawable/drawable-xhdpi but when i reference it

```
<LinearLayout

 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/details_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/bg">
...
</LinearLayout>
```

I get this error `Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/bg`

I tried copying it in every drawable-somethingDPI folder, because that's what I will do when I'll have the different size of it, but still nothing.

Finally, if I simply move it to the parent folder `/drawable` everything works.

But this is nonsense! I want to put the different sized pictures in their respective -DPI folder to support the various dpi buckets.

What am I missing?

Comment: To the down voter: you know that not all questions must be smart? I searched for my problem thoroughly before asking, and as a matter of fact i was missing something not related at all with the actual problem. But whatever makes your day mate. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's is a very sense one as you give it path

```
@drawable/bg
```

and the real path is

```
drawable/drawable-xhdpi/bg
```

when you create the different drawable folders create it in the res package not inside the drawable itself

Comment: Ha! thank you! I missed that those folders needed to be created in res and not in drawable itself! I'll accept the answer as soon as the system allows me to

Answer (score 0):

Max, Android Studio takes images or resources according to resolution from  drawable-somethingDPI folder. But if your Mobile or device have different resolution or don't support that resolution then It won't load and will give you error.

Note: if you put your Images inside drawable folder than drawable is supported by all screen resolution. So this is the reason behind that when you put images inside drawable it works.